# Network connection stops functioning when using the interfaces file to configure wireless

Tags: networking, server

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 server on a low powered machine that I intend to use as a testbed for home automation. I am trying to keep this machin connected to our wifi at all times so it can communicate with other devices on the LAN.

I have installed wpa_supplicant and configured wifi via the interfaces file in order to get it to automatically connect to our wifi on boot:

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug ens32
iface ens32 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid ThePromisedLan
wpa-psk password123
```

This works relatively well, and I'm able to ssh in for a while, but minutes later, I always lose connection. `iwconfig` and `ip addr` both seem to indicate that it is still connected to the network and has an ip address, but all attempts to communicate fail. Both `iwconfig` and my router show varying signal quality levels so I think it's still connected, but the networking seems to break for no reason.

Various output while it's having this issue (still being connected to the network but unable to communicate):

`curl google.com`

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
```

`ifconfig -a wlan0`

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:83:b8:d7  
          inet addr:192.168.0.247  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76da:38ff:fe83:b8d7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:146660 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:78917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25091392 (25.0 MB)  TX bytes:29000341 (29.0 MB)
```

`ping 192.168.1.1`

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6013ms
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

`route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Additionally, it will also completely disconnect from the network, with all utilities indication to AP association. This may have a similar cause or maybe it's an entirely different problem.

I haven't installed any networking packages since fresh installation besides wireless tools and wpa supplicant, so I don't think anything could be interfering with the interfaces configuration. Obviously, rebooting temporarily solves the problem, but it only gives me several minutes of network connectivity before it breaks again.

Does anybody know why networking would break like this?

Comment: Hi there! Do you have any other devices other than `wlan0` as I see `allow-hotplug` where both are on **dhcp**. Might be that it is causing the problem. If `ens32` is what acting as a LAN for example, make it **manual** while providing a static IP with no gateway where the internet then will route through the wireless interface. I maybe wrong but I'm assuming that could be the reason.

Comment: I don't plug anything into ens32 since I can't run a cable to my router anyways (I set it to allow-hotplug so it wouldn't stop boot for 5 minutes), but I can try setting it to manual to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Are you also able to log in to the PC directly to see what's exactly causing this issue. As in, when you don't have the connectivity, would you please login to the server directly and post us the output of `ifconfig -a`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` & `route -n`

Comment: Yep, I have it hooked up to peripherals for testing. I'll add that to the question if it happens again - I replaced the thermal paste and I haven't had the issue in the 40 minutes of uptime it has since...

Comment: It finally had issues again, but this time it completely disconnected from the network for 10-15 minutes, and it reconnected by itself. resolv.conf looks correct, but I have yet to look at that file when it looses connectivity while still being connected to the network. Do you have any tips for keeping it connected to the network? Maybe I should quit using interfaces and use network manager or something?

Comment: It just had the previous problem where it says it's connected but I can't ping my router or communicate to it at all. I'll edit in the output of those commands as soon as I can connect to it to copy/paste it.